# When does a webpage need a `last-modified`-header?

Tags: http-headers

According to Firebug, this is the header that my website returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 19 Dec 2014 08:41:34 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.35
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=200
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
```

**Why does it not send a `last-modified`-header, and should it?**

Answer (score 0):

The exact meaning of this header field depends on the implementation of the origin server and the nature of the original resource. For files, it may be just the file system last-modified time. For entities with dynamically included parts, it may be the most recent of the set of last-modify times for its component parts. For database gateways, it may be the last-update time stamp of the record. For virtual objects, it may be the last time the internal state changed.

An origin server **MUST NOT** send a Last-Modified date which is later than the server's time of message origination. In such cases, where the resource's last modification would indicate some time in the future, the server MUST replace that date with the message origination date.

An origin server **SHOULD** obtain the Last-Modified value of the entity as close as possible to the time that it generates the Date value of its response. This allows a recipient to make an accurate assessment of the entity's modification time, especially if the entity changes near the time that the response is generated.

HTTP/1.1 servers **SHOULD** send Last-Modified whenever feasible.

Comment: Okay, so if a server should send a LM, why doesn't mine? And why doesn't Stack Overflow?

Comment: Hard to say. It's depend on server configuration.  e.g  Apache does not send the last modified on SSI pages, because these values are difficult to calculate for dynamic content. Or maybe some module configuration (mod_expire).